# Ubuntu 16.04 not booting

Tags: boot

I recently changed boot mode from UEFI HardDisk to UEFI Pendrive, I didn't install anything from pendrive 
Now even after removing my pendrive I'm not able to boot to Ubuntu

It takes me to Dell testing

Comment: Have you tried to set the BIOS to its default values?

Comment: I did but got no bootable device found

Comment: Depending on your PC model, simply go to BIOS settings by pressing `<Delete>`or `<Esc>` key and select load default values then save and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Set default BIOS settings. For that, you have to open BIOS menu and there you will have the option "Reset to default settings". Select that, then save and quit.
Then you will be able to boot in hopefully.

Comment: I did, but got no bootable device found

Comment: Then you have to install bootloader. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i97y5Y2nChs go to this link and follow the instructions

Answer (score 0):

I got my os back

All I did was 
In bios added boot option and selected the HardDisk 
And named it as Ubuntu 16.04 
And selected file as grubx86_64.efi and applied it

And got everything back!

Thanks for the help guys